# Getting a resize event to happen every time a jQuery UI tab click occurs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, slick.js

I'm using jQUery UI tabs, and within each tab, it's got a slick.js-based slider.

Since the second slider is initially set to `display:none;` on page load (since it's in a non-active tab), its size isn't calculated correctly.

If once the second tab is active, the window is resized, it calculates the slick slider's sizing correctly.

Here's the HTML markup (slightly simplified for example purposes)

```
<div class="sampleRoadmapsTabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#year1">Year<br /><span class="num">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#year2">Year<br /><span class="num">2</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="year1">
        <div class="slider sliderContent">
            <div>
                Year 1, Slide 1 Content
            </div>

            <div>
                Year 1, Slide 2 Content
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /sliderContent -->
    </div>
    <!-- /year1 -->

    <div id="year2">
        <div class="slider sliderContent">
            <div>
                Year 2, Slide 1 Content
            </div>

            <div>
                Year 2, Slide 2 Content
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /sliderContent -->
    </div>
    <!-- /year2 -->
</div>
<!-- /sampleRoadmapsTabs -->
```

I've searched and found others using the window resize on tabsactivate, so setup the JS like this:

```
//Fires jQuery UI tabs instance(s)
    $(function() {
        $(".tabs").tabs();
        $(".sampleRoadmapsTabs").on( "tabsactivate", function( event, ui ) 
        {
            $(window).triggerHandler("resize");
        } );
        $(".tabs").fadeIn(500);
    });
```

While this fixes going from tab 1 to tab 2 (#year1 to #year2 in the above example), going back to the first tab, the resize doesn't automatically get fired again, so the tab one is broken after clicking from #year2 and then back to #year1 tab.

How do I get the window triggerHandler resize event to happen on every successive tab click, rather than the initial? Is it due to the fact I'm not classing/id'ing the individual slick sliders uniquely?

Comment: Rather than trigger a resize event it would make more sense to instantiate the library on the elements once their tabs  become visible. Depending on the plugin you're using you can hook to the events raised in order to achieve this